# Client-server persists connection, do i need to re-connect and re-logging every time the iPhone locked?

Tags: iphone, sockets, logging, connection, reconnect

Im developing an iPhone app with client-server design, the server manage client connection with sockets and keep an array of all the currently connected clients. 
This way i get persists connection between client and server, and i can send messages from the server to the clients when ever i need.
My problem is on the client side, the iPhone user. every time the phone get locked the connection is lost so i need to re-connect and re logging again when the user unlock the iPhone.
Is this the way to go? Or am I doing it wrong? please help..

Answer (score 1):

A RESTful protocol may be more suitable for mobile use.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i already implemented it this way.. any suggestions?